# My prefix is where we are

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

<sub>*My First 'Riley Riddle' - hopefully not too hard or easy:*</sub>

> My prefix is where we are.
>
> My infix is done with force over a distance.
>
> My suffix is castled for safekeeping.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

is it

> networking

My prefix is where we are.

> we are on the net

My infix is done with force over a distance.

> definition of work

My suffix is castled for safekeeping.

> the king is castled in chess

Comment: Oh, I completely had the wrong mindset for the suffix explanation. Nice thought! :D